# replace parts of variable string in dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string

I have data frame:

```
     SINGLE_MEM                     crd    
1          5        -97.75514500005232 30.263874000727306
2          8        -97.81095799930782 30.234157000528484))) 
3          3        ((-97.68044500036247 30.267636999839592 
4          2        -97.71808637589912 30.1848525102668))  
5         10        -97.76847799967814 30.432537999903005  
6          6        -97.6937453403672  30.46382579769979
```

In crd column i have coordinates in character. I need to replace all '( )'
on a gaps. I replace ')', '))', ')))' by

```
df$crd <- gsub(")))", "", df$crd)
df$crd <- gsub("))", "", df$crd)
df$crd <- gsub(")", "", df$crd)
```

but i cant replace a '(', '((', '(((' because i have an error: `Error in gsub ("((", "", df $ crd): Incorrect regular expression '((', reason 'Missing') ''`

Comment: Try `gsub("[(]|[)]","","((())) ")`

Comment: @Jimbou oh it works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
gsub("[()]+", "", df$crd)
```